# Waves not showing at final render

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I want to distort this video shown in image (Image as plane) to create circular waves when the finger touches the mirror (picture 1).[image] just like the one in picture 2.

[image]

So I used the wave modifier and also Dinamic paint.
In theory the waves are there in the viewport but when rendered the image looks totally flat.

How can I achieve the wavy look at the final render?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Dynamic Paint*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html#dynamic-paint) is the answer, but it seems to be a little tricky here. But this works...

For your "mirror', it should be a [*canvas*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html#canvas) of type *waves*.

[image]

The object should be fairly subdivided, so I used a [*Subdivision Surface*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) above the Dynamic Paint in the stack.

Here is the modifier stack for our mirror:

[image]

Next, I used an icosphere for the [*Brush*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/brush.html#brush) in this example.

The settings are at the default.

[image]

---

Finally, the brush (icosphere) is animated from one point to another to contact the canvas, scale is also animated to increase on contact. Here, we have a cube parented to the icosphere, something like this may be an option in your scene. Constraints such as Copy Transform, and Limit Scale may be useful for that purpose. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Timaroberts T1000 likes this
 Neat effect