# Water Oscillations in Tipping Tray

Tags: fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to create a simulation of a tray tipping backwards and forwards with water inside it, that is oscillating in waves, (like it would in real life). I am a Blender beginner so I have no idea how to go about doing this.

This is the kind of tray I want o simulate with water in it.

[image]

And I want it to move like this with water inside it so as the tray tilts backwards and forwards the water oscillates in waves

[image]

Comment: Hello :). It would be great if you could add some images to illustrate what you're going for :).

Comment: Probably related, but more information would be useful, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/206652/15924